# Not sure what red wire for combination bathroom light/exhaust is for

Tags: electrical, wiring, smart-switch, lightning

I’m replacing the original switch with a smart switch. When I opened it up, it seems whoever installed it previously used a regular light switch.

The red wire went straight into the old light switch (where a black wire would usually go).

One black wire was screwed in. The other black wire went straight in.

Below are pictures of the original switch and my wiring of the smart switch. I would just cap the red wire?

What could the red wire be used for in the future? It is not hot as tested with a contact tester.

https://ibb.co/hKLNrXB https://ibb.co/C24ZDYW

Comment: Post the "before" pictures.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you think a wire connected to the old non-smart switch would **not** be connected to the new smart switch? If anything, a smart switch often requires *more* wires, commonly (but not always) needing a white neutral wire added.

In any case, **colors don't matter in US wiring**. Or rather, they only matter a little:

- Neutral is white. White is not always neutral (some 3-way, 2-wire 240V, etc.)
- Green, bare, yellow/green - ground.
- Black, red, blue, yellow, etc. - hot, switched hot, traveler, etc.

So the "usually black" is simply because of what you have seen. In a modern 3-wire switch loop, it will usually be red. In conduit - black, red, blue, yellow, etc.

In your case, the most likely setup is:

- The two blacks (one on screw, one backstab) are effectively daisy-chained. If your new switch can legitimately take two wires under a screw (screw-to-clamp), great. If not, use a pigtail to get them together with one short black wire that then goes under the screw. Or if the switch comes with pigtails, connect it to the two black wires.
- The red wire is the "switched hot". Connect it to "switched hot" or "load" on the new switch.

Comment: The red wire is not hot per my contact tester. Hence the red wire should not be connected to the line or load on the smart switch?

Comment: In the fan/light fixture the red wire is most likely a switched hot for either the fan or the light. So the red wire must be connected to the switch to send power to the fixture. And it must be connected to the same side of the switch as the other switched hot. If you would mistakenly connect it to the same side as the line hot then the light or the fan would be ON even if the switch was OFF.

Comment: If all you want to do is to make the light and fan independent of each other, you could get a "double switch". This is two switches in the space of one ordinary switch.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a three conductor cable from the switch box to the fixture (Black, Red, White, plus uninsulated ground). If you had two switches in the box, this would allow separate control of the light and the fan, if the light/fan fixture allowed this. But since you have only one switch the light and fan were operated in unison.

One way to do this would be to connect three wires to the switch. The line hot (a black wire) would be connected to one side of the switch. The switched hots (a red and a black) would be connected to the other side of the switch. In the fixture one switched hot would connect to the light and the other switched hot would connect to the fan. This seems to be what you had originally.

Another way to do this would be to connect only one of the switched hots (B or R) to the switched side of the switch and not use the other switchable wire at all. In the fixture housing you would use a short wire "a jumper" connecting the light and the fan terminals.

What functionality do you want to achieve with these smart switches?

Comment: The bathroom light and exhaust is one device and only controlled by one switch.


I have seen other setups where the exhaust fan and the bathroom light are two different devices and thus controlled by two separate switches.


I wired the smart switch with one black to line, one black to load, ground to green, neutral to white as a test.


The exhaust fan/light turns on and works.


I am not sure what switched hot is. Any sources I can read to learn?

Comment: A light + exhaust fan in a single unit can be designed to allow independent control of the light and the fan. Looks to me like yours is that type. In our bathrooms we have a triple combo light + exhaust fan + heat lamp in one unit which are independently controlled by three witches in a triple gang box. All three use the same neutral. An ordinary simple switch has two wires connected to it: One is the "line hot" which is always hot.The other is called the "switched hot". It is hot when the switch is closed (ON) and not hot when the switch is open  (OFF).

Comment: The line hot goes back to the electrical panel and is always hot (if the breaker in the panel is ON). The switched hot from a switch goes to the appliance or device being controlled by the switch. When the switch is open (OFF) then the appliance is not powered. When the switch is closed (ON) the power from the line hot connected to the other side of the switch is connected to the appliance and it can operate.

Comment: These single unit fixtures with light + exhaust fan have a connection block in the unit which has a single neutral connection but two separate connections for the switched hots for  the light and the fan. This allows the light and fan to be controlled independently if you have two switches.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea "A light + exhaust fan in a single unit can be designed to allow independent control of the light and the fan."

The red wire is a switched hot and thus can be used with another switch if I wanted to independently control the light and fan.

Since I will be turning the light and fan on at the same time, do I have to wire this with the load in my smart switch? Or can I cap it?

Comment: I highly doubt this light and exhaust fan can be controlled independently. I have another one downstairs where I replaced the switch with a smart switch. There was no extra wire. It looks the same but there is no way to verify unless I take it apart.

Looks like this red wire was installed when the home was built to give the option of having a separate light and fan. However, the previous home owner seemed to not opt for this option based on the fact this is because this is a single gang box.

Comment: Do you want to control them separately if you could? Or are you satisfied with the two being in unison? When these units are installed it is possible that the fan and the light are connected together with a strap which the electrician can cut if the installation calls for separate control with two switches. It is also possible that the default is separate control and the installer must connect them with a "jumper" for control in unison.  It could be that some modern residental codes require the exhaust fan to be on when the light is on to force the users to use the fan.

Comment: We still have the original 1970 builder's units in our two bathrooms which have light, exhaust fan and heat lamp with its own fan in one unit but controlled by three separate switches.

Comment: I am satisfied with the two being in unison. I do not want to go through the hassle of having to cut drywall, buying a bigger electrical box, installing two gangs, etc.



Can I just cap the red wire for now? Or should I try attaching the red wire to my load (black wire) to the smart switch?


The smart switch would have it's wire, the red wire, and the load wire from the wall.

Comment: If you turn on the power with the red disconnected and both light and fan work, then just cap the red. If one or the other does not work, then you will have to connect the red to the load side of the switch.The way to tell if the red is being used in your installation is to connect it to the load side of a switch and turn the switch ON. According to you the red was originally connected to the switch and it worked, right? Your identical unit in the other bathroom doesn't have a red wire but the light and fan switched hot connections might be connected in the housing.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: A double switch allows a single line hot to supply the line side of two separate switches packaged together to fit in a single gang box.  The load sides of the two switches would have separate wires (one black and one red) with one going to the light and the other going to the fan, assuming they are not connected in the fixture.

Comment: When you figure out how to connect things so they work, please report what worked.

Comment: This works. "If you turn on the power with the red disconnected and both light and fan work, then just cap the red."


I will try the following later
1. switch line hot with switch hot red wire and leave the single line hot wire unconnected
2. bundle load black wire with the switch hot red wire

Comment: No need to try the other things you mentioned. You evidently have a voltage tester, is it a non contact tester? With the red wire capped if you turn on the light and fan is the red wire hot? If it is not hot, then it is not connected in the light/fan fixture. If it is hot then it is connected but is not needed. In either case just cap it and fold it out of the way.

Comment: Fluke 1AC-A1-II VoltAlert Non-Contact Voltage Tester


I'm actually heading up to put everything away. I'll test and see if it is hot when it is switched on.

Comment: With the red wire capped if you turn on the light and fan is the red wire hot?-Yes.



I folded it and put it out of the way. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: All the light/fan exhaust in my house seem to be the same model. No way to verify unless I take it apart but they all look the same.


I can confirm the fan and light can be switched independently. One bathroom is wired this way with two switches.


One bathroom does not have a switch hot wire.


This bathroom we are talking about has a switch hot.



This has been interesting in finding out how the wiring was done for each bathroom.

Comment: "One bathroom does not have a switch hot wire."  If it has a switch, it has a switched hot. A standard mechanical switch has two wires attached to it--a line hot and a switched hot. When the switch is OFF the switched hot is not hot; when the switch is ON the switched hot is hot.  Wireless signaling or smart switches are a different matter.